# High CPU windows server IIS 7.5 processes php-cgi.exe remain high CPU although no visitors in website

Tags: php, iis

I run my wordpress PHP website on windows server IIS 7.5. I have noticed that even there are no visitors in my website, some php-cgi.exe still running for long time. each of them (15-20%), so together CPU get almost (100%) slowing down my websitee when a new visitoer comes in.

I turned off all plugins, I turned off rewrite rules but nothing helped.

What can be done in order to stop php-cgi.exe process from running after visitor letf my webiste? or any other idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is specific to the PHP instead of IIS.
There are so many reasons that lead to high CPU usage when the `PHP-cgi.exe` process consumes 100% CPU in the Task Manager.
Such as the Malformed PHP scripts containing some infinite loop, these poorly coded scripts will call the `PHP-cgi.exe` PHP worker program on the server and will eat 100% of CPU.
A large number of PHP processes on the server take up a considerable amount of server resources. Every user instance creates a large amount of process on the server. As a result, the CPU usage shoots up.
Besides, if there is something wrong with fetching certain content with lacking user privileges, PHP can cause high CPU usage.
See this blog for more details.
https://bobcares.com/blog/php-cgi-exe-high-cpu/

Comment: Quote from the above link: “Also, if that happens to be a malicious script, we straightaway disable it and that would bring the server CPU usage back to normal.” So how do you find the malicious script causing the high CPU assuming you know the application pool?